# CSS Validator library for Java

Tags: java, css, validation

I am looking out for a css validator library that I can use in my java application. I have checked out this.  http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/manual.html. But according to my understanding that needs to be run on a server locally or used as a command line tool. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Behind the link you have posted there is a webservice which you can use to validate your CSS files. But you have to be online for doing this. There is also an offline version available: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/DOWNLOAD.html which you might can embed in your application.

Comment: I believe you are referring to the css-validator.jar file. Is there any javadoc available for the same which I can refer to for using the classes inside it?

Comment: I found the JavaDocs [here](http://blueprintcss.googlecode.com/svn/blueprint/trunk/lib/blueprint/validate/css-validator-javadoc.jar)

Comment: That JAR doesn't actually have the Javadocs in them.  Open it up and take a look.